# Gazebo4 packages installed with rosdep

Tags: ros, rosdep, gazebo-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

**Short version:** Is there any way I can install gazebo4_ros related packages (`msgs`, `plugins`, `ros_control` and `ros`) with rosdep? Thank you!

**Long version**
I want to use Gazebo 4 together with ROS Indigo. I has to manually install the gazebo4 and gazebo ROS related packages and it is working properly. However, I would like to know if there is any way to setup the `package.xml` of my package so that these packages are automatically installed with rosdep.

If I include

```
<build_depend>gazebo_ros</build_depend> 
<build_depend>gazebo_plugins</build_depend>
```

I get the following error when running rosdep:

```
 ros-indigo-gazebo-ros : Depends: gazebo2 but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libsdformat1 but it is not going to be installed
```

Which is expected because I already have Gazebo 4. And if I include

```
    <build_depend>gazebo4_ros</build_depend> 
    <build_depend>gazebo4_plugins</build_depend>
```

Then it fails because rosdep cannot find those packages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213620/gazebo4-packages-installed-with-rosdep/) by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1305 on 2015-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As gazebo is a system dependency, you would need to add it to the `rosdep` [definitions](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/base.yaml#L714-727), which are used to lookup the respective packages.

There is a [how-to about contributing rosdep rules](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html).

But I'm not sure how this would be handled by the maintainers, as it actually introduces depedency conflicts between different packages. This is out of my league ;-)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1